# Older version of Gramps for OSX

Tags: gramps

To recover from 'bsddb unknown version' I am searching for an old version of Gramps.
I took some time to find out Gramps had an error with 9 of the 16 family trees. The most used trees can still be opened in 4.0.3-1. OSX is 10.11.2. My guess is that OSX upgrades caused the problem.
I know the upgrade docs of Gramps specifies to backup each family tree before upgrading. But they are not available.
I'd like to try to roll back to a previous version, open the failing family trees, backup them, and import these backups in new trees in the recent version Gramps.

Comment: Hi pvanbus - could you clarify what exactly is your question? You want to download version 4.0.3-1? You can download many old versions here: http://sourceforge.net/p/gramps/activity/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a serious problem with the current Gramps file format. (We are switching databases in Gamps 5.0 to prevent this from happening again.)

If you can't find a version that will open it, you might try:

- see if you can "dump" the data with a command-line db-dump command (probably will have to download Berkeley DB tools)
- see if you can find someone to open them for you.

The Gramps-users mailing list may be a better source of help as well.